# I keep getting `NullInjectorError` when running Angular 17 project

Tags: angular, authentication, angular17

I am trying to use Angular 17 to create a project but I keep getting an error when I go to run it. I can't seem to figure out how to get passed this. Copilot keeps wanting me to make changes to the `app.module.ts` file, but I don't have that. I only have the `app.component.ts` file and it doesn't have `@NgModule`.

```
main.ts:5 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[_AuthGuard -> _AuthService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NavigationEnd, Router, RouterLink, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, RouterLink, HttpClientModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.sass'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  currentRoute = ''

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.currentRoute = event.url
      }
    })
  }
}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './pages/sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth/auth-guard.service';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignUpComponent },
];
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>
  public currentUser: Observable<any>

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const localUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser')

    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(localUser ? JSON.parse(localUser) : null)
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable()
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): any {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value
  }

  login(loginName: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`/api/auth/login`, { loginName, password })
      .pipe(map(user => {

        if (user && user.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user))
          this.currentUserSubject.next(user)
        }
        return user
      }))
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser')
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null)
  }
}
```

auth-guard.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called')
    if (!this.authService.currentUserValue) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using the standalone components and bootstrapping the Angular application with the standalone component as the root component, you should inject the `HttpClientModule` in the application injector via the `bootstrapApplication` method.

> You can add the list of providers that should be available in the application injector by specifying the providers field in an object passed as the second argument.

```
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    ...,
    provideHttpClient()
  ],
});
```

Next, the `HttpClientModule` should be removed from the `imports` array as not needed.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.sass'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

Another reference: [Configuring dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#configuring-dependency-injection)