# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError Standalone NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient

Tags: angular, httpclient

Im getting this error:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_LoginComponent])[HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! in angular.
```

Here is my code :
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[package.json[app.module.ts[login.component.ts]

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Do I have to import or provide `HttpClient` somewhere else or in my Login component? I tried to provide it in my component and then i get the same error message but it says that there is no provider for `HttpHandler`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You are declaring the login component, but as it's standalone you need to import it.

Comment: check this question answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77623050/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-httpclient/77623090#77623090)

Answer (score 0):

Since `login.component` is standalone, you need to import `HttpClientModule` to the `imports` array!

> ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_LoginComponent])[HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! in angular.

1. Login component has the problem
2. HttpClient, belongs to HttpClientModule - hence we need to import this module inorder to use it!

If `login.component` is a standalone component, then it should not be present in the `declarations` array of any module! it should be in `imports` array!